# Would it be wise to feed k-means results into a cmeans?

Tags: clustering, natural-language, k-means, text-mining, fuzzy-c-means-clustering

I am conducting a cluster analysis of documents using document embeddings as the input to the algorithms. One of the problems I am coming across is that in reality there are documents that belong to more than on "cluster" when looking at things from a human perspective, which led me to cmeans/fuzzy kmeans

My kmeans is performing quite well, aside from the aforementioned issue with some documents really being in multiple clusters which isn't being accounted for. CMeans on the other hand isn't performing well at all when feeding it with the same data and setting the same k

I was thinking of using the cluster centres from the kmeans as the centres for cmeans and was wondering people's thoughts on this?

also, perhaps feeding initial membership degrees to the cmeans based on every document having a 1 in the kmeans cluster it resides in and a 0 for every other cluster could perhaps help?

I'm relatively new to this so would appreciate any guidance